# Graphs in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net

I want to show the sales data graphically.
How to do it?  Any code examples?
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 3):

For charts on .NET, you should look at the [Microsoft chart controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c).

There are samples [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart).

Comment: +1 for the MS Chart controls. Just a note that these controls need .net 3.5 SP1

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [ZedGpraph](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page).

Here's their [VB.NET reference page](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Visual_Basic_Reference_Code_for_Sample_Charts).